# Laravel middleware throttle

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет,
мне необходимо для некоторых рутов увеличить throttle с 60 до 100, но я не уверена, что это решение верное

```
Route::post('/{planId}/continue', [PlanStepsAPIController::class, 'continue'])->name('continue')->middleware(
    'throttle:300,1'
);
```

вот что находится в Kernel.php

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
            //
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:api',
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 1):

для того, чтобы перетереть middleware laravel необходимо указать

```
Route::post('/{planId}/continue', [PlanStepsAPIController::class, 'continue'])->name('continue')->withoutMiddleware('throttle:api')->middleware('throttle:300,1');
```